# Retrieve rows on the basis of two different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have two tables (`Emp` and `EmpCopy`) in a SQL Server database with following data:

Case 1:  data in `Emp` and `EmpCopy` table present like below:

```
Table:  Emp

Id      Name
-----------------
1      Emp_Name
2      Emp_Age
3      Emp_City
```

Table: EmpCopy

```
Id  Name
--------------------
1   Emp_Name
2   Emp_Age
```

Case 2: Data in Emp and EmpCopy table present like below:

```
Table:  Emp

Id      Name
--------------------
1   Emp_Name
2   Emp_Age

Table: EmpCopy

Id      Name
---------------------
1   Emp_Name
2    Emp_Age
3    Emp_City
```

Now according to cases given above I want retrieve records from both the tables, just like given below

Case 1:

```
Id  Emp_Column  EmpCopy_Column
1   Emp_Name    Emp_Name
2   Emp_Age Emp_Age
3   Emp_City    NULL
```

Case 2:

```
Id  Emp_Column  EmpCopy_Column
1   Emp_Name    Emp_Name
2   Emp_Age Emp_Age
3   NULL        Emp_City
```

Comment: Please reply ASAP? Maybe consider improving your question so you get a correct answer. Have you ever tried to create a query? Post it on your question.

Comment: @Yaroslav Did you notice this is a new user? Did you miss http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith did you noticed that when I commented there where already 6 votes down? Precisely I recommended to update the question and to post the query, if there was one. I did not voted down precisely because is a new user. And also edited the question to try to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT ISNULL(A.Id,B.Id) Id, A.Name Emp_Column, B.Name EmpCopy_Column
FROM Emp A
FULL JOIN EmpCopy B
ON A.Id = B.Id
```